# How to remove short code using jquery?

Tags: jquery

My themes generates a short code but it does not works and looks ugly. Here it is:

```
<div class="vc_col-sm-12 vc_gitem-col vc_gitem-col-align-left">
[vc_btn link="post_link" title="Read more" style="flat" shape="rounded" color="juicy-pink" size="md" align="left"]
</div>
```

I want to remove  all  [vc_btn link="post_link" title="Read more" style="flat" shape="rounded" color="juicy-pink" size="md" align="left"]. How can I do this?

Comment: " [vc_btn link="post_link" title="Read more" style="flat" shape="rounded" color="juicy-pink" size="md" align="left"] " this is the only string it generate every time ?

Is there any wrapper around it which identifies this string ?

Comment: Abdus, did any of the answer help you or do you still face a problem

Comment: Yes. I got an answer which works fine. I am posting my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove everything between and including `[` and `]`, then try the code below:

Hope it helps

```js
var s = $('.vc_gitem-col').text().trim();

s = s.replace(/\[.*?\]/, "")
$('.vc_gitem-col').text(s)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_col-sm-12 vc_gitem-col vc_gitem-col-align-left">Content
[vc_btn link="post_link" title="Read more" style="flat" shape="rounded" color="juicy-pink" size="md" align="left"] removed
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
 $(function () {
        $(".vc_gitem-col-align-left").contents().filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType != 1;
        }).replaceWith("");
    });
```